# how to manually use an "internal" meteor package?

Tags: meteor, bcrypt, meteor-packages

I'm using meteor and I have accounts-password package installed, so it came with bcrypt.
Good thing because I want to use it to manually hash some other data.

I do have this package in my packages.json ("bcrypt": "^4.0.1") and I can see its folder in ./.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt

However I can't figure out how to use it "manually". I tried importing, I tried simply using bcrypt.hash() but it throws an error saying it is undefined. Tried const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

How do I do this ?

Comment: If it is undefined but you have imported it correctly there is probably another error causing this to be a followup error. The code in the provided answer should work unless there are other issues in your code.

Comment: Are you trying to import from the client? bcrypt relies on compiled addons and so is server-side only

Comment: yes on the client. I don't want non hashed info on server. I managed it by adding bcryptjs to with meteor npm

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this npm to your own project as well

```
meteor npm install --save bcrypt
```

and then use `import` that to your source like

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

// this is equivalent to the standard node require:
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
```

Read more at meteor guide

https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html

Good luck

Comment: humm, I get that, but I thought I could avoid it because it is already in my packages. The files are here. If I npm install it, won't I have the code twice ?

Comment: During development propably but when running "build" it will be optimized so far I know.

Comment: `build` is not that smart and will happily bundle duplicates. Thankfully, because bcrypt was already in `package.json` it's not a duplicate so will only be bundled once!

Comment: Thanks for clearing @fred-stark - in any case eagle1 that should have solve your issue - be aware of comment from fred about client and server usage